# MYSQL and PHP code shows match and unmatched entry in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem.please can anyone help me. thank you in advance.
here it is.
I have two tables, shown below

tab1

```
  id  |  name  |  input_1
  1   |  mon   |   A
  2   |  ryan  |   Q
  3   | cedie  |   K
  4   | jane   |   D
```

tab2

```
  id  |  input_2

  1   |    A

  2   |    R

  3   |    k

  4   |    S
```

what i want to happen is to show all rows with their name and echo if input_1 and input_2 is match. for now I have this query.I know there is something missing.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tab1`
INNER JOIN `tab2` ON tab1.id = tab2.id") or die(mysql_error);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
  if($row['input_1']==$row['input_2'])
   {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "Your input match!";
   }
  else
   {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "Your input didn't match!";
   }
 }
```

but it shows that all my input are matched even some value don't match.what is wrong?please help.I'm just a beginner in PHP.PLEASE help.

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_* API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: Use a left join between table 1 and table 2

Comment: You should print out input_1 and input_2 values as well for debugging purposes. You would see why the code claims to have a match where you think there is no match. Your code is supposed to be doing what you require.

Comment: DO NOT USE A LEFT JOIN BETWEEN TABLE 1 AND TABLE 2 (its not going to fix the problem as you have described it. It is worth considering if you want to deal with scenario of missing rows)

Comment: `if(trim($row['input_1'])==trim($row['input_2']))`  use trim()

Comment: @devpro: extra whitespace would give rise to false negatives - not false positives as reported.

Comment: thanks.left join doesnt work.

Comment: trim() works great..thank you for the help to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this(if you do not want `CASE-SENSITIVE` check):

```
SELECT * FROM
tab1 t1
   INNER JOIN 
tab2 t2
   ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE UPPER(t1.input_1) = UPPER(t2.input_2)
```

And this(if you want `CASE-SENSITIVE` check):

```
SELECT * FROM
tab1 t1
   INNER JOIN 
tab2 t2
   ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.input_1 = t2.input_2
```

Answer (score 0):

The data and code you have shown us here *will not* produce the outcome you described. (note there is some ambiguity about id=3).

Make sure this code matches what is *executing* on your server (note that if you are using an opcode cache, it may be configured to NOT check for changes to files).

Answer (score 0):

I am on mobile so I'll format this later.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT t1.name, t1.input_1, t2.input_2 FROM tab1 t1 JOIN tab2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id") or die(mysql_error);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
 {
  if($row['input_1']==$row['input_2'])
   {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "Your input match!";
   }
  else
   {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "Your input didn't match!";
   }
 }
```